# Unordered analog of chain in lattice theory

Tags: terminology, lattice-orders

In lattice theory, a **chain** is a fully ordered subset of a lattice, corresponding to a vertical path in a Hasse diagram. What is a fully *unordered* subset called, corresponding to a horizontal row in a Hasse diagram? Or is it just called an equivalence class?

Comment: [Antichain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antichain).

Comment: @bof, you were first. You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A set of pairwise incomparable elements of a partially ordered set is called an *antichain* or a *Sperner family* or a *clutter*; see the Wikipedia page "[Antichain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antichain)" or "[Sperner family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner_family)". (Note, however, that the term "antichain" is also used by some to mean "[strong antichain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_antichain).)